# Register multiple classes w/ Objectify

Tags: java, objectify

Is it ok to register multiple classes with Objectify4? I mean, two entity with same class name like `com.mycompany.MyEntity` or `org.mycommunity.MyEntity`

Comment: Not familiar with Objectify4 bt there two clases you give in your example do have different names. The package is included in the name. Or you could actually try it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work but you will need to specify a different name for one of them:

```
@Entity(name="OtherEntity")
```

This name is what becomes the *kind* in the datastore.  It defaults to the class shortname.